# JS добавлять ссылку а не заменять

Tags: javascript, html

помогите с JS

Имеется код, который при нажатие на radio изменяет ссылку.
Но мне нужно что бы он добавлял значение к ссылке а не изменял ее, при этом перезагружая страницу

Вот мой код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[value=nabor]').on('click', function() {
        window.location.href = 'nabor';
    });
    $('input[value=tovar]').on('click', function() {
        window.location.href = 'tovar';
    });
});
/********************************************/
function SetData (elem) { 
    localStorage.setItem(elem.getAttribute('name'), elem.getAttribute('id'));
} 
function GetData (item) { 
    return localStorage.getItem(item); 
}

window.onload = function() {
    var Item = GetData ('type');
    if(Item != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(Item).checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" class="checkset" value="nabor" id="nabor" onchange="SetData(this);"><label for="nabor"> показать только наборы </label>
        
        <input type="radio" name="type" class="checkset" value="tovar" id="tovar" onchange="SetData(this);"><label for="tovar"> показать только товары </label>
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте вместo

```
window.location.href = "tovar"
```

это

```
window.location.href += "tovar"
```